# Ubuntu Server for MongoDB installation

Tags: mongodb

Is it mandatory to have Ubuntu Server 16.04 in order to install and work properly with MongoDB on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not mandatory to install the "server" image to get MongoDB to work properly.  It might be "recommended" but MongoDB will run just fine on the 16.04 "desktop" image as well.

> Why is it recommended?

Because the "desktop" image includes extra packages (like a GUI/Desktop) that can consume resources.  This can hurt the performance of things like a database.  So for production, server-based images are usually the best way to go.

Comment: Why is it recommended?

Comment: @sphoenix Edit made.